# UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width gives me reversed values

Tags: ios, swift, bounds, uiscreen

I need to have the correct width when rotating the device. I check the value and it works fine to update the value when rotating, except it gives me the width of the device reversed. So when I turn landscape, it gives me the width of the device in portrait and vice versa. Is there any solution to this?

For example UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width with an iPad in landscape gives me width 810.0 and in portrait: 1080.0.

Thanks!

```
var widthConstant: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    // Override view did load function
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        // Rotation detection
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    // Remove the rotation detection when deinitializing
    deinit {
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func rotated() {
        // Update the view again after rotating
        
        widthConstant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        self.widthAnchorConstraint = tableView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant)
        print("WIDTH:", widthConstant)
    }
```

Output:

```
WIDTH: 1080.0 (device is turned portrait)
WIDTH: 810.0 (device is turned landscape)
```

Comment: It would be much easier and make more sense to constrain your table view's width relative to the view controller's view. Is there any reason why you are doing it this way specifically? `UIDevice.main.bounds` likely has not been updated yet when that notification is fired.

Comment: You can consider using `func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` instead.